# Checkbox click in webpage?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, checkbox

Thanks.

I am pretty sure I need to work around the iCheck-helper..

Comment: Where have you got that JS code from?

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know how you get on.

Comment: still nothing.. I think it is somehow protecting from me doing it...

Comment: I do wonder if that JavaScript is undoing our efforts.

Comment: it most lilkely is and I believe doing something to make it real per say keydown and keyup is required...the js code is from the click event!

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes have an attribute `Checked`, you need to set that to true.

```
test.setAttribute("checked", "true");
```

Or with the value attribute...

```
test.setAttribute("value", "1");
```